# How use aggregate and match in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collection ProductInventories and ProductDetails. The ProductInventories has a prodId that is connected to the id of ProductDetails. I want to get all the product that is Active only.

```
const products = await ProductInventory.find().populate({
    path: 'prodId',
    model: ProductDetails,
    populate: { path: 'category', select: 'category_name', model: Category },
  });
```

I'm using this code to get all the data, but I want to have a condition that it will return the item that is isActicve = True. I'm just using a filter function to filter all active data. I want to learn how to use aggregate and match.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the lookup aggregation from ProductInventories to ProductDetails based on the prodId field,  then do a match aggregation with field isActive = true

```
db.ProductInventories.aggregate([
   { 
    $lookup: { 
        from: "ProductDetails",
        localField: "prodId",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "product_details"
    },
    $match: {
        isActive: true
    }
}
])
```

Refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code and its working now. Thanks also for helping @smitha t m.

```
 const products = await ProductInventory.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'productdetails',
        localField: 'prodId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'product',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$product',
    },
    {
      $match: { 'product.isActive': true },
    },
  ]);
```